# java: HashMap<String, int> not working

Tags: java, generics

`HashMap<String, int>` doesn't seem to work but `HashMap<String, Integer>` does work.
Any ideas why?

Comment: your choice of words for your question is confusing, can you clarify? And exactly what is not working, can you post the code?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can't use primitive types as generic arguments in Java. Use instead:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

With [auto-boxing/unboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) there is little difference in the code. Auto-boxing means you can write:

```
myMap.put("foo", 3);
```

instead of:

```
myMap.put("foo", new Integer(3));
```

Auto-boxing means the first version is implicitly converted to the second. Auto-unboxing means you can write:

```
int i = myMap.get("foo");
```

instead of:

```
int i = myMap.get("foo").intValue();
```

The implicit call to `intValue()` means if the key isn't found it will generate a `NullPointerException`, for example:

```
int i = myMap.get("bar"); // NullPointerException
```

The reason is [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Unlike, say, in C# generic types aren't retained at runtime. They are just "syntactic sugar" for explicit casting to save you doing this:

```
Integer i = (Integer)myMap.get("foo");
```

To give you an example, this code is perfectly legal:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<Integer, String> map2 = (Map<Integer, String>)myMap;
map2.put(3, "foo");
```

Comment: Your last example doesn't work: Cannot cast from Map<String,Integer> to Map<Integer,String>

Comment: considering each separate code in a new line, the code on line 5 must be first casted to Integer before using the intValue() method because it is considered as an object when you use the get() method.

Answer (score 5):

GNU Trove support this but not using generics. http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TObjectIntHashMap.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use primitive types in `HashMap`. `int`, or `double` don't work. You have to use its enclosing type. for an example

```
Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Now both are objects, so this will work.

Answer (score 1):

int is a primitive type, you can read what does mean a primitive type in java [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp), and a Map is an interface that has to objects as input:

```java
public interface Map<K extends Object, V extends Object>
```

object means a class, and it means also that you can create an other class that exends from it, but you can not create a class that exends from int.
So you can not use int variable as an object. I have tow solutions for your problem:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

or

```java
Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<>();
int x = 1;

//put x in map
int[] x_ = new int[]{x};
map.put("x", x_);

//get the value of x
int y = map.get("x")[0];
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use reference type in generic arguments, not primitive type.
So here you should use

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and store value as

```
myMap.put("abc", 5);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question