# SparseArray vs HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sparse-matrix

I can think of several reasons why `HashMap`s with integer keys are much better than `SparseArray`s:

1. The Android documentation for a `SparseArray` says "It is generally slower than a traditional `HashMap`".
2. If you write code using `HashMap`s rather than `SparseArray`s your code will work with other implementations of Map and you will be able to use all of the Java APIs designed for Maps.
3. If you write code using `HashMap`s rather than `SparseArray`s your code will work in non-android projects.
4. Map overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` whereas `SparseArray` doesn't.

Yet whenever I try to use a `HashMap` with integer keys in an Android project, IntelliJ tells me I should use a `SparseArray` instead. I find this really difficult to understand. Does anyone know any compelling reasons for using `SparseArray`s?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

[`SparseArray`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java) can be used to replace [`HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) when the key is a primitive type.
There are some variants for different key/value types, even though not all of them are publicly available.

Benefits are:

- Allocation-free
- No boxing

Drawbacks:

- Generally slower, not indicated for large collections
- They won't work in a non-Android project

`HashMap` can be replaced by the following:

```
SparseArray          <Integer, Object>
SparseBooleanArray   <Integer, Boolean>
SparseIntArray       <Integer, Integer>
SparseLongArray      <Integer, Long>
LongSparseArray      <Long, Object>
LongSparseLongArray  <Long, Long>   //this is not a public class                                 
                                    //but can be copied from  Android source code
```

In terms of memory, here is an example of `SparseIntArray` vs `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` for 1000 elements:

`SparseIntArray`:

```
class SparseIntArray {
    int[] keys;
    int[] values;
    int size;
}
```

Class = 12 + 3 * 4 = 24 bytes
Array = 20 + 1000 * 4 = 4024 bytes
Total = **8,072 bytes**

`HashMap`:

```
class HashMap<K, V> {
    Entry<K, V>[] table;
    Entry<K, V> forNull;
    int size;
    int modCount;
    int threshold;
    Set<K> keys
    Set<Entry<K, V>> entries;
    Collection<V> values;
}
```

Class = 12 + 8 * 4 = 48 bytes
Entry = 32 + 16 + 16 = 64 bytes
Array = 20 + 1000 * 64 = 64024 bytes
Total = **64,136 bytes**

Source: [Android Memories by Romain Guy](https://speakerdeck.com/romainguy/android-memories) from slide 90.

The numbers above are the amount of memory (in bytes) allocated on heap by JVM.
They may vary depending on the specific JVM used.

The `java.lang.instrument` package contains some helpful methods for advanced operations like checking the size of an object with `getObjectSize(Object objectToSize)`.

Extra info is available from the official [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).

Class = 12 bytes + (n instance variables) * 4 bytes
Array = 20 bytes + (n elements) * (element size)
Entry = 32 bytes + (1st element size) + (2nd element size)

Comment: Can somebody guide me where those "12 + 3 * 4" and "20 + 1000 * 4" come from?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, he showed a presentation (https://speakerdeck.com/romainguy/android-memories) where a class occupies 12 bytes + 3 variables of 4 bytes, an array (reference) occupies 20 bytes (dlmalloc - 4, object overhead - 8, width&padding - 8).

Comment: For the record, another key disadvantage of SparseArray is that as an Android object it needs to be mocked for unit testing.  Where possible I now use Java's own objects to simplify testing.

Comment: @DavidG You can just use [unmock plugin](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin) to mock android dependencies.

Comment: Why Entry is 32 byte + (1st element size) + (2ns elements size),There is key,value,hash,next,  4 pointer ,the size should be 4*4=16

Comment: Even if you are not doing Android, copying the class to your project is not hard, it only depends on 3 other classes. APL license means its ok to do that, whatever license you are working with.

Comment: Why can't we use it in non-Android project?

Answer (score 41):

I came here just wanting an example of how to use [`SparseArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html). This is a supplemental answer for that.

## Create a SparseArray

```
SparseArray<String> sparseArray = new SparseArray<>();
```

A `SparseArray` maps integers to some `Object`, so you could replace `String` in the example above with any other `Object`. If you are mapping integers to integers then use [`SparseIntArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html).

## Add or update items

Use [`put`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#put(int,%20E)) (or [`append`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#append(int,%20E))) to add elements to the array.

```
sparseArray.put(10, "horse");
sparseArray.put(3, "cow");
sparseArray.put(1, "camel");
sparseArray.put(99, "sheep");
sparseArray.put(30, "goat");
sparseArray.put(17, "pig");
```

Note that the `int` keys do not need to be in order. This can also be used to change the value at a particular `int` key.

## Remove items

Use [`remove`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#remove(int)) (or [`delete`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#delete(int))) to remove elements from the array.

```
sparseArray.remove(17); // "pig" removed
```

The `int` parameter is the integer key.

## Lookup values for an int key

Use [`get`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#get(int)) to get the value for some integer key.

```
String someAnimal = sparseArray.get(99);  // "sheep"
String anotherAnimal = sparseArray.get(200); // null
```

You can use [`get(int key, E valueIfKeyNotFound)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#get(int,%20E)) if you want to avoid getting `null` for missing keys.

## Iterate over the items

You can use [`keyAt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#keyAt(int)) and [`valueAt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#valueAt(int)) some index to loop through the collection because the `SparseArray` maintains a separate index distinct from the `int` keys.

```
int size = sparseArray.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    int key = sparseArray.keyAt(i);
    String value = sparseArray.valueAt(i);

    Log.i("TAG", "key: " + key + " value: " + value);
}

// key: 1 value: camel
// key: 3 value: cow
// key: 10 value: horse
// key: 30 value: goat
// key: 99 value: sheep
```

Note that the keys are ordered in ascending value, not in the order that they were added.

Answer (score 23):

> Yet whenever I try to use a HashMap with integer keys in an android
>   project, intelliJ tells me I should use a SparseArray instead.

It is only a warning from this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) of it sparse array:

> It is intended to be more memory efficient than using a HashMap  to
>   map Integers to Objects

The `SparseArray` is made to be **memory efficient** than using the regular HashMap, that is does not allow multiple gaps within the array not like HashMap. There is nothing to worry about it you can use the traditional HashMap if you desire not worrying about the memory allocation to the device.

Comment: The points about saving memory are obviously valid, but I've never understood why android couldn't have made SparseArray<T> implement Map<Integer, T> so that you get a memory efficient Map implementation - the best of both worlds.

Comment: @PaulBoddington also remember `SparseArray` prevents the key integer to be Auto box which is another operation and cost performance. rather than Map it will autobox the primitive integer to `Integer`

Comment: Also true, but if they'd overloaded the put method by including one with signature put(int a, T t) you'd still be able to put key-value pairs into the map without keys being auto-boxed. I just think that the Collections Framework is so powerful (one of the best reasons for using Java) that it's madness not to take advantage of it.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Collections are based on objects not on primitive so it wont work within the Collections API

Comment: [1/4] @PaulBoddington, if `SparseArray<T>` implemented `Map<Integer, T>` and also defined an overload of methods such as `put` that takes an `int`, there are two posibilities:

Comment: [2/4] 1) you hold references of type `SparseArray` and call `put` on those, in which case the overloaded `put` method is used and no boxing is involved — but it defeats the purpose of implementing `Map`;

Comment: [3/4] 2) you hold references of type `Map` and call `put` on those, in which case the `put` method defined in `Map` is used and the argument is boxed — which defeats the purpose of using `SparseArray`.

Comment: [4/4] The reason to what I'm claiming is static dispatch. The JVM does not support dynamic dispatch, so if you hold references of type `Map`, the JVM can't possibly know it should call an overload defined in a subtype instead.

Comment: Have you seen the key ranges in the quoted benchmark? I am very sure in less special setups HashMap will perform way better.

Answer (score 13):

After some googling I try to add some information to the already posted anwers:

[Isaac Taylor](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/android-performance-tweaking-parsearray.html) made a performance comparision for SparseArrays and Hashmaps. He states that

> the Hashmap and the SparseArray are very similar for data structure
>   sizes under 1,000

and

> when the size has been increased to the 10,000 mark [...] the Hashmap
>   has greater performance with adding objects, while the SparseArray has
>   greater performance when retrieving objects. [...] At a size of 100,000 [...] the Hashmap loses performance very quickly

An comparision on [Edgblog](https://edgblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/sparsearray-vs-hashmap/) shows that a SparseArray need much less memory than a HashMap because of the smaller key (int vs Integer) and the fact that

> a HashMap.Entry instance must keep track of the references for the
>   key,  the value and the next entry. Plus it also needs to store the
>   hash of the entry as an int.

As a conclusion I would say that the difference could matter if you are going to store a lot of data in your Map. Otherwise, just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 11):

A sparse array in Java is a data structure which maps keys to values. Same idea as a Map, but different implementation:

1. A Map is represented internally as an array of lists, where each element in these lists is a key,value pair. Both the key and value are object instances.
2. A sparse array is simply made of two arrays: an arrays of (primitives) keys and an array of (objects) values. There can be gaps in these arrays indices, hence the term “sparse” array.

The main interest of the SparseArray is that it saves memory by using primitives instead of objects as the key.

Answer (score 5):

> The android documentation for a SparseArray says "It is generally
>   slower than a traditional HashMap".

Yes,it's right. But when you have only 10 or 20 items , the performance difference should be insignificant.

> If you write code using HashMaps rather than SparseArrays your code
>   will work with other implementations of Map and you will be able to
>   use all of the java APIs designed for Maps

I think most often we only use `HashMap` to search a value associated with a key while `SparseArray` is really good at this.

> If you write code using HashMaps rather than SparseArrays your code
>   will work in non-android projects.

The source code of SparseArray is fairly simple and easy to understand so that you only pay little effort moving it to other platforms(through a simple COPY&Paste).

> Map overrides equals() and hashCode() whereas SparseArray doesn't

All I can say is, (to most developers)who care?

Another important aspect of `SparseArray` is that it only uses an array to store all elements while `HashMap` uses `Entry`, so `SparseArray` costs significant less memory than a `HashMap`, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that the compiler issues a warning.  I guess HashMap has been way overused for storing items.

SparseArrays have their place.  Given they use a binary search algorithm to find a value in an array you have to consider what you are doing.  Binary search is O(log n) while hash lookup is O(1).  This doesn't necessarily mean that binary search is slower for a given set of data.  However, as the number of entries grows, the power of the hash table takes over.  Hence the comments where low number of entries can equal and possibly be better than using a HashMap.

A HashMap is only as good as the hash and also can be impacted by load factor (I think in later versions they ignore the load factor so it can be better optimized).  They also added a secondary hash to make sure the hash is good.  Also the reason SparseArray works really well for relatively few entries (<100).

I would suggest that if you need a hash table and want better memory usage for primitive integer (no auto boxing), etc., try out trove. (http://trove.starlight-systems.com - LGPL license). (No affiliation with trove, just like their library)

With the simplified multi-dex building we have you don't even need to repackage trove for what you need.  (trove has a lot of classes)