# Duplicate item's index in linkedHashSet

Tags: java, indexing, set, linkedhashset

I am adding some values to a `LinkedHashSet` and based on `add()` method's output i.e. true/false, I am performing other operations.

If the `Set` contains duplicate element it returns false and in this case I want to know the index of the duplicate element in the `Set` as I need to use that index somewhere else. Being a 'linked' collection there must be some way to get the index, but I couldn't find any such thing in `Set`/`LinkedHashSet` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet` is not explicitly indexed *per se*. If you require an index, using a `Set` for such application is usually a sign of wrong abstraction and/or lousy programming. `LinkedHashSet` only guarantees you predictable iteration order, *not* proper indexing of elements. You **should** use a `List` in such cases, since that's the interface giving you indexing guarantee. You can, however, infer the index using a couple of methods, for example (**not recommended**, mind me):

a) use indexed iteration through the collection (e.g. with `for` loop), seeking the duplicate and breaking when it's found; it's O(n) complexity for getting the index,

```
Object o; // this is the object you want to add to collection
if ( !linkedHashSet.add(o) ) {
    int index = 0;
    for( Object obj : linkedHashSet ) {
        if ( obj == o ) // or obj.equals(o), depending on your code's semantics
            return index;
        index++;
    }
}
```

b) use `.toArray()` and find the element in the array, e.g. by

```
Object o; // this is the object you want to add to collection
int index;
if ( !linkedHashSet.add(o) )
    index = Arrays.asList(linkedHashSet.toArray()).indexOf(o);
```

again, O(n) complexity of acquiring index.

Both would incur heavy runtime penalty (the second solution is obviously worse with respect to efficiency, as it creates an array every time you seek the index; creating a parallel array mirroring the set would be better there). All in all, I see a broken abstraction in your example. You say

> I need to use that index somewhere else

... if that's *really* the case, using `Set` is 99% of the time wrong by itself.

You can, on the other hand, use a `Map` (`HashMap` for example), containing an `[index,Object]` (or `[Object,index]`, depending on the exact use case) pairs in it. It'd require a bit of refactoring, but it's IMO a preferred way to do this. It'd give you the same order of complexity for most operations as `LinkedHashSet`, but you'd get O(1) for getting index essentially for free (Java's `HashSet` uses `HashMap` internally anyway, so you're not losing any memory by replacing `HashSet` with `HashMap`).

Even better way would be to use a class *explicitly* handling integer maps - see [HashMap and int as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148575/hashmap-and-int-as-key) for more information; tl;dr - http://trove.starlight-systems.com/ has `TIntObjectHashMap` & `TObjectIntHashMap` , giving you possibly the best speed for such operations possible.

Comment: @maximus335 true, I've been using custom Collections with array-based constructors for some time, basic Java ones doesn't have them, corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as of now it solved my problem and saved my ass