# Return 2 counted values from one function

Tags: java

I want to create a function which returns two counted values. The values are counted by iterating over a for-loop.

For example, I have an array of persons (male, female, adults, children) and I only want to find the amount of boys (child + male) and the amount of women (adult + female).

In the last few years I've been writing in javascript and this is how I would have done it in javascript.

```
function countBoysAndWomen() {
    var womenCounter = 0;
    var boysCounter = 0;

    for (var p of persons) {
        if (p.isAdult() && p.isFemale()) womenCounter++;
        else if (p.isChild() && p.isMale()) boysCounter++;
    }

    return {amountOfWomen: womenCounter, amountOfBoys: boysCounter};
}
```

Now my problem is, how do I return such an object in java? Do I need to create a new class? What would you call that class?

Isn't that extremely inefficient, having a complete class only for this one small purpose?

What if I wanted to count a different pair of values? Would I have to create another entirely new class?

Is this below actually the best way of creating such a function?

```
private Counter countBoysAndWomen() {
     Counter counter = new Counter();

     for (Person p:persons) {
         if (p.isBoy()) counter.addBoy();
         else if (p.isWomen()) counter.addWoman();
     }

     return counter;
}
```

Of course, another option would be to seperate the function into the functions "countBoys()" and "countWomen()" but then I'd have to iterate over the array twice and that wouldn't be optimal right?

Comment: That is one way of doing it. You can also store it in array and return array.

Comment: There are any number of ways this could be implemented, e.g., a simple map of `String` => `Integer` which would be the closest to your JS example. "Inefficient" in what sense? Either language creates an object regardless, the only real difference is that in JS you can do whatever you want with an anonymous object, in Java it's typed--it's up to you *how* it's typed.

Comment: @DaveNewton the map is a good idea. With inefficient I meant wasted lines of code... for something you need one line in javascript you would need an entire new class in java.

Comment: Just count it separately. You want to separate the concerns, and not do everything at the same time. That will make your code more readable and maintainable over time. Optimize it only if it turns out to be an actual performance bottleneck.

Comment: @IceRevenge *shrug* It's "one line" in JS because that's how you wrote it. Java isn't JS: there are different semantics all across the board, and those semantics buy you something JS doesn't offer. Using Java like JS will lead you down a path of creating the same types of errors in Java you can get in JS and (roughly) defeats the purpose. Simple DTOs in Java can be written and never thought about again; that they exist barely matters in terms of cognitive overhead.

Comment: I wrote an answer that I hope helps.  With that said, `How would you create that kind of function?` really isn't a great way to ask questions on stack overflow - and I suspect someone will flag this question, because it invites a lot of opinions and can lead to more of a discussion rather than an "answered question".

Comment: BTW, one observation - Java is strongly typed while JS is not.  That allows JS to be more succinct.  In Java, you must have some class definition to hold those values.  Using `Map` is the probably the closest you will get to javascript's `{amountOfWomen: womenCounter, amountOfBoys: boysCounter}`

Comment: I recommend not getting to worked up on performance and functionality together.  Determine what type of performance you need, then work to that.  For example, if the code will work with lists of 100s of values, don't worry about iterating over the list more than once - unless it is being called a large number of times inside of another loop.  On the other hand, if the lists have millions of entries or more, then it would be wise to keep stats - perhaps in a containing class that is updated as entries are added or removed.

Comment: @ash  Maybe that is actually the best way... but if you say it makes the code more maintainable, wouldn't I duplicate a lot of code if I made seperate functions? That's not very maintainable, right?

Comment: @IceRevenge more classes may be less maintainable.  In my experience - code that is easier to understand ("Real Obvious Code") is best in that regard, so the amount of code is secondary.  If you end up with dozens or more classes all doing just about the same thing, then that's a concern.  One or two - I wouldn't even think about it.  Figuring out the "best balance" in any code is something I believe comes mostly with experience and with experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are some good Answers, especially [the one by ash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124013/642706), they address the specific question raised in the Title about returning two values. However, you raised two other questions that show the larger problem.

## Premature Optimization

> Isn't that extremely inefficient, having a complete class only for this one small purpose?

Always go with **clean design first**. Do not build an initial design on some imaginary possible performance issue or on excessive worry about efficiency. Processors do two to four *billion* instructions per second nowadays, so we can afford a little bit of inefficiency. Making code clear, easy to read, easy to debug, and easy to modify is almost always more important than efficiency.

On top of that, programmers of all caliber are notoriously bad at predicting performance and bottlenecks. Do not muddy your design with compromises until you have a *proven* measurable bottleneck of some significance.

> What if I wanted to count a different pair of values? Would I have to create another entirely new class?

That question points to the clumsiness of your trying to combine queries that should be separate.

Let's write some code. First, the `Person` class.

### Enum

Notice that we have nested two enums, `Gender` & `Maturity`. If not familiar, see [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). The enum facility in Java is *much* more useful, flexible, and powerful than in other languages. Using strings as value flags is clumsy and error-prone. The compiler cannot help you with typos. In contrast, the compiler *can* help you with enums, bringing [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) to your code while ensuring valid values.

Bonus benefits to using enums: Very little memory used, and very fast to execute.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Person
{
    public enum Gender
    {
        FEMALE, MALE
    }

    public enum Maturity
    {
        ADULT, CHILD
    }

    // Members
    private UUID id;
    private Gender gender;
    private Maturity maturity;

    // Constructor
    public Person ( UUID id , Gender gender , Maturity maturity )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull ( id );
        Objects.requireNonNull ( gender );
        Objects.requireNonNull ( maturity );

        this.id = id;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.maturity = maturity;
    }

    // Accessors

    public UUID getId ( )
    {
        return id;
    }

    public Gender getGender ( )
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public Maturity getMaturity ( )
    {
        return maturity;
    }

    // Object overrides

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", gender=" + gender +
                ", maturity=" + maturity +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass () != o.getClass () ) return false;
        Person person = ( Person ) o;
        return id.equals ( person.id );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash ( this.id );
    }
}
```

Write a method `countPeople` that takes a `List` of `Person` objects, along with your pair of criteria (gender & maturity).

We can pass any combination of gender and maturity. This design continues to work even as you add values to your enums, such as `Gender.UNKNOWN` and `Maturity.ADOLESCENT`.

```
private Integer countPeople ( List < Person > people , Person.Gender gender , Person.Maturity maturity )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull ( people );
    Objects.requireNonNull ( gender );
    Objects.requireNonNull ( maturity );

    Integer count = 0;
    for ( Person person : people )
    {
        if ( ( person.getGender ().equals( gender ) ) && ( person.getMaturity ().equals( maturity ) ) )
        {
            count = ( count + 1 );
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And, write some code to exercise that counting code.

The `List.of` syntax is new in Java 9 and later, creating an unmodifiable `List` object of an indeterminate concrete class in one simple line of code.

```
List < Person > people = List.of (
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.FEMALE , Person.Maturity.CHILD ) ,
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.FEMALE , Person.Maturity.ADULT ) ,
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.MALE , Person.Maturity.ADULT ) ,
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.FEMALE , Person.Maturity.CHILD ) ,
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.MALE , Person.Maturity.ADULT ) ,
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.MALE , Person.Maturity.CHILD ) ,
        new Person ( UUID.randomUUID () , Person.Gender.FEMALE , Person.Maturity.ADULT )
);

Integer women = this.countPeople ( people , Person.Gender.FEMALE , Person.Maturity.ADULT );
Integer boys = this.countPeople ( people , Person.Gender.MALE , Person.Maturity.CHILD );
```

Report.

```
System.out.println ( "people = " + people );
System.out.println ( "women = " + women );
System.out.println ( "boys = " + boys );
```

> people = [Person{id=1ac225e6-f21c-49f5-82d5-8e0f289f16e0, gender=FEMALE, maturity=CHILD}, Person{id=333828cc-48e6-4d0c-9937-66f3168445bd, gender=FEMALE, maturity=ADULT}, Person{id=4d37bc08-1e1f-4806-8d84-dc314b6b2cd8, gender=MALE, maturity=ADULT}, Person{id=0cd2a38a-5b01-4091-9cb2-c0284739aa70, gender=FEMALE, maturity=CHILD}, Person{id=36d9af87-3cbb-44bc-bf03-67df45a5d8c8, gender=MALE, maturity=ADULT}, Person{id=2fef944a-79c9-4b29-9191-4bc694b58a4d, gender=MALE, maturity=CHILD}, Person{id=ffc8f355-9a4b-47c3-8092-f64b6da87483, gender=FEMALE, maturity=ADULT}]
>
> women = 2
>
> boys = 1

---

### Streams

We could get fancy and use streams in place of that `for` loop. Not necessarily better in this case, but more fun.

We are going to call `Stream::count`. This returns a long, so change our use of 32-bit integer to 64-bit long. Or else you could cast the long to an integer.

Calling [`List::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) generates a stream of the `Person` objects held in the list.

A [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) object holds our test for gender and our test for maturity. The call to [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) applies the predicate to select objects. These get counted by a call to [`Stream::count`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count()).

```
private Long countPeople ( List < Person > people , Person.Gender gender , Person.Maturity maturity )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull ( people );
    Objects.requireNonNull ( gender );
    Objects.requireNonNull ( maturity );

    Predicate < Person > predicate = ( Person person ) -> ( person.getGender ().equals ( gender ) && person.getMaturity ().equals ( maturity ) );
    Long count = people.stream ().filter ( predicate ).count ();
    return count;
}
```

Tip: Performance with very large lists of people *might* be better if you went the next step, to [parallelize the stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream()).

---

### Databases

If this data were coming from a database, you should be doing this work within that database, rather than on the Java side. Database engines such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) are *highly* optimized to do just this kind of selecting, comparing, sorting, and counting work.

Answer (score 3):

You can call below method from your main function or any method. it will return a map of desired value. in below code i am assuming that persons is a list. but if person is an array, change size() with length method.

```
public HashMap<String,Integer>  countBoysAndWomen() {

        int womenCounter = 0;
        int boysCounter = 0;
        HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < persons.size() ; i++ ) {

            if (p.isAdult() && p.isFemale()){
              womenCounter++;
            }
            else if (p.isChild() && p.isMale()) {
            boysCounter++;
            }
        }
         hm.put("women",womenCounter );
         hm.put("boy" , boysCounter);

         return hm;
     }
```

for retrieving hashmap value :-

```
 for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : hm.entrySet())  
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                             ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
    }
```

Comment: This is a decent solution due to being easy to understand as well as easy to implement.

Comment: in java 9+, can be abbreviated to `Map.of("women", womenCounter, "boy", boysCounter)`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher still on java8. planning to learn java9. bydwe thanks a lot. its good to know that people are always helping each other to be better and answer better.

Comment: Very cool. Wasn't aware of maps... one more question, why does HashMap<String, int> not work but HashMap<String,Integer>? What is the difference?

Comment: whole another book. please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780385/java-hashmapstring-int-not-working   if still have doubt comment here. I will try to clear it.

Comment: @IceRevenge `Collections` such as `HashMap` can only hold an `Object`, such as `Integer` or `String` or a custom object.  `int` is a primitive, though due to autoboxing most of the time the values can used interchangeably.  Trust me this a big a rabbit hole to get into...

Comment: This method should be declared as `public Map<String,Integer>  countBoysAndWomen()` -- it returns a _Map_ but the caller doesn't care about which particular _implementation_ of Map is used internally in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than solutions using `Map`, I would propose you create a private class in which you can store the result:

```
private class People {
    public int boys = 0;
    public int women = 0;
}
```

The class can be used as an inner class of where your `countBoysAndGirls` method is located. Rather than making the method return `Map`, you can make it return `People` (I couldn't come up with a better name for the `People` class).

Generally, placing items in a map isn't really great as the keys can vary and get out of sync with what you expect in other places in your code. Making a private class with actual variables, ensures compile-time safety and is semantically much more powerfull.

Comment: And what do you do about the problem that if you want to count a different value-pair? You would need to create a new private class every time right?

Comment: @icerevenge correct. But it is something that should only rarely happen. Otherwise it's a strong indication that you are not modelling your code correctly. I do admit though, that Java falls short here and doesn't have tupple data types.

Comment: Of course, you could rename those fields from `boys` and `women` to something very generic, like `stat1` and `stat2`.  Then reusing the object would be more straight-forward.  I wouldn't recommend it most of the time, but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

So in Java, there is unfortunately no concept of returning multiple values from a method.  The following are reasonable choices, each with benefits/disadvantages:

- Create a model object to hold the values (one field for each value to be used)
- Return an array or list with the values
- Return a Map from the function with keyed values
- Return a Map.Entry with the two values (other, similar objects exist)
- Pass an argument into the method that will hold the results (e.g. pass in a Map)
- Move the method into a new class of its own that stores the results, add one field for each value, and add getters to retrieve the results

Choosing a solution often depends on context - such as whether this is internal processing within a class that will be written and used one time, versus a method that will be reused over a significant portion of the code.

One of the key disadvantages of most of the solutions is the lack of fail-fast when things change, or a caller doesn't properly adhere to the contract.  "Fail Fast" (meaning, getting mistakes to cause failures as early as possible during the development process) is sacrificed when using generic constructs.

For example, using a model object, an IDE or compiler will tell you when the caller to the function tries to access a field that does not exist.

On the other hand, using a Map, you won't find out the caller is asking for the wrong field name until runtime.  And, if the returned value could be null, you may not be able to distinguish "wrong field name" from "value was null" at all.

For what it is worth - most of the time, I go for the model object approach unless this is a 1-time internal use that is all within one class file.  While adding the class is "overhead", the fail-fast and self-documenting nature of the solution is valuable.

Q: "Isn't that extremely inefficient, having a complete class only for this one small purpose?"

A: No, it isn't inefficient.  Try writing a micro performance test and create a large number of these classes.  The only real downside is having to write and maintain the additional class, with the upside of fail-fast described above.

Q. "What if I wanted to count a different pair of values? Would I have to create another entirely new class?"

A. No, the class could be reused.  Of course, if the field names don't line up, then it would be awkward, and ill-advised, to reuse the class.  With that said, the class could be written in a way that is more generic and reusable, with the downside of being less self-documenting and potentially harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

So, first, let's assume we have some collection of Persons:

```
var persons = initializePersons();
```

Next, we assume that Person has a few information methods, where the implementing classes can determine what exactly those methods return:

```
public interface Person
{
    boolean isAdult();
    boolean isMale();
    default boolean isChild()
    {
        return !isAdult();
    }
    default boolean isFemale()
    {
        return !isMale();
    }
}
```

Now, we can process `persons` like so:

```
var women = persons.stream().filter(Person::isAdult).filter(Person::isFemale).count();
var boys = persons.stream().filter(Person::isChild).filter(Person::isMale).count();
```

Finally, we can return the values in a `Map<String, Long>`, like so:

```
return Map.of("women", women, "boys", boys);
```

All in all:

```
public Map<String, Long> countBoysAndWomen()
{
    var persons = initializePersons();
    var women = persons.stream().filter(Person::isAdult).filter(Person::isFemale).count();
    var boys = persons.stream().filter(Person::isChild).filter(Person::isMale).count();
    return Map.of("women", women, "boys", boys);
}
```

Comment: That's an odd mix of java and javascript!  `var persons` is javascript, not java - in that `Public Map<String, Long> countBoysAndWomen()` java method.

Comment: @ash It's legal java, since Java 10, I believe. See [JEP 286](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

Comment: Oh - good to know.  I don't do a great job of keeping up with the latest java releases.  I'm mostly on 8 now.

Answer (score 0):

*You must not necessarily return the counters to get access to their values outside Your function*

```
Optional<Integer> boysCount;
Optional<Integer> womenCount;

private void countBoysAndWomen() {
  int boys = 0;
  int women = 0;
  for( Person p: persons ) {
    if( p.isBoy() ) boys++;
    else if( p.isWomen() ) women++;
  }
  boysCount = Optional.of( boys );
  womenCount = Optional.of( women );
}

countBoysAndWomen();

System.out.println( "boys: " + boysCount.get() );
System.out.println( "women: " + womenCount.get() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you a modern and true Java approach employed in Stream API and implemented in the [`[Int/Long/Double]SummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) classes.

```
final class Person {
    private final Gender gender;

    public Person(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    // one method that returns the gender
    // no isWoman, isMan methods
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}

enum Gender {
    MAN,
    WOMAN;
}

final class PersonGenderStatistics implements Consumer<Person> {
    private final Map<Gender, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

    // the number is calculated for every gender
    @Override
    public void accept(Person person) {
        count.compute(person.getGender(),
             (gender, count) -> count == null ? 1 : ++count);
    }

    // combines two statistics
    public void combine(PersonGenderStatistics other) {
        count.putAll(other.count);
    }

    // gives the summary for the given gender
    public Integer getCountByGender(Gender gender) {
        return count.get(gender);
    }
}

final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(Gender.MAN),
                new Person(Gender.WOMAN),
                new Person(Gender.WOMAN),
                new Person(Gender.WOMAN),
                new Person(Gender.WOMAN),
                new Person(Gender.WOMAN),
                new Person(Gender.MAN),
                new Person(Gender.MAN)
        );

        final PersonGenderStatistics statistics =
                persons.stream()
                        .collect(
                                PersonGenderStatistics::new,
                                PersonGenderStatistics::accept,
                                PersonGenderStatistics::combine
                        );

        System.out.println(statistics.getCountByGender(Gender.MAN));    // 3
        System.out.println(statistics.getCountByGender(Gender.WOMAN));  // 5
    }
}
```